# Regex for removing part of URL param

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I am trying use regex to remove a particular param in a url.

```
//Here are the scenarios of what I want to remove in the url
'?pIds=123,2311' => ''
'?pIds=123,2311&deal=true'  => '?deals=true'
'?pIds=123' => ''
'?pIds=123&deals=true'  => '?deals=true'

'&pIds=123,2311' => ''
'&pIds=123,2311&deals=true' => '&deals=true'
'&pIds=123' => ''
'&pIds=123&deals=true' => '&deals=true'


const a = '?pIds=123,2311&deals=true';
a.replace(/&?pIds=\d+,?\d+/i, '');
```

Is this possible to create a single regex for these scenarios? How can I conditionally have ? or & there if pIds is the first or middle param, respectively?

Comment: I would recommend parsing out the query string into a nice map/dictionary structure, remove the keys you don't need, then recreating the query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in Javascript for searching:

```
/[?&]pIds=[^&]*$|([?&])pIds=[^&]*&/
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `[?&]pIds=[^&]*$`: Match `?` or `&` followed by `pIds=`. `$` ensures this is the only parameter in query string.
- `|`: OR
- `([?&])pIds=[^&]*&`: Match `?` or `&` followed by `pIds=` followed by `&`. This is the case where there is one more parameter in query string.

**Code:**

```js
var arr=['?pIds=123,2311',
'?pIds=123,2311&deal=true',
'?pIds=123',
'?pIds=123&deals=true',
'&pIds=123,2311',
'&pIds=123,2311&deals=true',
'&pIds=123',
'&pIds=123&deals=true'];

var re = /[?&]pIds=[^&]*$|([?&])pIds=[^&]*&/;

for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i], ' => ', arr[i].replace(re, '$1'));
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/34eN8c/3)

Comment: you solution works great! Can you explain what the '$1' do that is replacing the match regex?

Comment: also, why is the linefeed \n needed in the first part of the regex?

Comment: `\n` is not really needed in regex. It was only used for regex101 demo since there are multiple input in separate lines. Also `$1` represents first capturing group i.e. `([?&])` in right hand side of alternation.

Answer (score 2):

The regex to identify the block you are talking about is something like the following:

```
((?<=\?)|\&)pIds=\d+(,\d+)?
```

The first part is a "positive lookbehind" for a question mark, which will match if there is a question mark before `pIds`, but it will not include the question mark as part of the match.  An ampersand also works, but it is included as part of the match, so it will get deleted.

I also made the treatment of the optional comma and numbers a little bit clearer.  You always have one block of numbers (`\d+`), optionally followed by a comma and another block of numbers.

Edit: In my original post, I forgot to treat the ampersands properly.  If the string begins with a question mark and there is no ampersand, you want to delete the question mark.  If it starts with a question mark and ends with an ampersand, you want to delete the ampersand at the end.  If it both begins and ends with an ampersand, you need to delete one of them.  If it begins with an ampersand and does not end with one, you need to delete the one at the beginning.  The result is slightly more complicated and looks like this:

```
\?pIds=\d+(,\d+)?($|[^&])|(?<=\?)pIds=\d+(,\d+)?\&|\&pIds=\d+(,\d+)
```

The first case takes care of no ampersand at the end (`($|[^&])` corresponds to either end-of-line or no ampersand).  The second case takes care of beginning with `?` and ending with `&`.  The third case takes care of the remaining two scenarios, where there is a `&` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of ways to do this. Here is a version without regex:

```js
let url1 = 'foo.bar?pIds=123,2311&deals=true&foo=bar';
let parsedUrl;
let queryParts;

// Get the query string from the URL
parsedUrl = url1.split('?');

// Split the query string so we get each key value then filter so we dont get the pIds
queryParts = parsedUrl[1].split('&').filter(q => q.indexOf('pIds') === -1);

// set URL to the original hostname and a ? if we have a query still
url1 = (queryParts.length > 0 ? '?' : '')

// Join the query parts
url1 += queryParts.join('&')

console.log(url1);
```

More examples:

```js
let url2 = 'foo.bar?pIds=123,2311';
  parsedUrl = url2.split('?');
  queryParts = parsedUrl[1].split('&').filter(q => q.indexOf('pIds') === -1);
  url2 = parsedUrl[0] + (queryParts.length > 0 ? '?' : '')
  url2 += queryParts.join('&')
  console.log(url2);

  let url3 = 'foo.bar?foo=bar&pIds=123,2311';
  parsedUrl = url3.split('?');
  queryParts = parsedUrl[1].split('&').filter(q => q.indexOf('pIds') === -1);
  url3 = parsedUrl[0] + (queryParts.length > 0 ? '?' : '')
  url3 += queryParts.join('&')
  console.log(url3);
```